# No Sound in Steam-Client (Snap-Version)

Tags: sound, snap, steam

I installed Steam via Snap-Store (steam, 1.0.0.78, 171, latest/stable, canonical**)

For example, if I want to play an embedded YouTube video from the forum, I don't hear any audio. But when I start a game, everything works. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: I believe that for your problem you'd prefer to solve the issue without having to change from the snap version. However, I believe that the apt and the flatpak versions are more stable.

[sudo apt-get install steam -y] or [flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam]

Comment: @Figaro Jes, i switched back to the Flatpak Version and delete Snap complete. Much much better.

Comment: Please file a proper bug report with the Snap author for this issue. They can't fix it if they don't know about it.

Comment: There is already a bug report for that: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-runtime/issues/505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by deleting snap and switch to Flatpak.

Comment: If you've found solution to your problem yourself, you may want to accept your own answer.

Comment: Jep..17 hours left to accept.